# Unused space in sqlite

Tags: django, sqlite

I ran `sqlite3_analyzer` in order to try to understand why a database consumes much more disk space than expected, even after using `VACUUM`. The output shows that there are many tables with extra pages used for seemingly no reason. Here is an example:

```
*** Table ACCOUNT_EMAILCONFIRMATION and all its indices ***********************

Percentage of total database......................   2.6%    
Number of entries................................. 0         
Bytes of storage consumed......................... 12288     
Bytes of payload.................................. 0            0.0% 
Bytes of metadata................................. 24           0.20% 
Average payload per entry......................... 0.0       
Average unused bytes per entry.................... 0.0       
Average metadata per entry........................ 0.0       
Maximum payload per entry......................... 0         
Entries that use overflow......................... 0         
Primary pages used................................ 3         
Overflow pages used............................... 0         
Total pages used.................................. 3         
Unused bytes on primary pages..................... 12264       99.80% 
Unused bytes on overflow pages.................... 0         
Unused bytes on all pages......................... 12264       99.80%
```

Here, three pages, each 4,096 bytes are used to store zero entries.
The result is that a tiny database takes hundreds of KB. This makes me suspect that the database size might quickly explode when I put my Django website into production.

Why does this happen? How do I reclaim all this unused space and prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Each table and index uses at least 1 page. See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#pages).

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen? How do I reclaim all this unused space and prevent this from happening in the future?

You can reclaim unused space by using `VACUUM` *(or relying on `auto_vacuum` but this isn't as thorough)*. A brief explanation of why and what `VACUUM` does can be found at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html